# Trying to read a cookie on a different cookie domain using Google Tag Manager

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

My cookie domain is .mywebsite.com

I also have cookies stored on the domain [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)

I am trying to get Google Tag Manager to "read" a cookie on "www.mywebsite.com" in order to pass to Google Analytics.

Is this possible?

Using the cookie variable, GTM is not able to read the cookie name.

Answer (score 1):

If the cookie has the http-only attribute, you can't read it using JavaScript and/or GTM.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies?retiredLocale=de